# How to get metric for a spark pod OOMKilled using prometheus

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, out-of-memory, prometheus, grafana

I have a spark executor pod, which when goes to OOMKilled status, I want to alert it. I am exporting spark metrics using prometheus to grafana.

I have tried some queries to

```
kube_pod_container_status_last_terminated_reason{reason="OOMKilled"}
kube_pod_container_status_terminated_reason{reason="OOMKilled"}
```

They don't seem to give proper results. I am cross checking the result using humio logs, which is logging the OOMKilled properly.

```
container_memory_failures_total{pod="<<pod_name>>"}
```

Even this is not able to capture the problems of OOMKilled which is in sync with the humio logs. Is there any other proper metric to catch OOMKilled ?

Answer (score 1):

As i know there is two metrics which allow you to monitor OOM.
The first one is used for tracking OOMKilled status of your main process/pid. If it breach the limit pod will be restarted with this status.

```
kube_pod_container_status_last_terminated_reason{reason="OOMKilled"}
```

And the second one for gathering total count of OOM events inside the container. So every time some child process or other process will breach the RAM limit they will be just killed and metric counter increased. But the container will be working as usual.

```
container_oom_events_total
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that you can use to get alerted on `OOM` and other issues, one is certainly `container_oom_events_total` which is provided by cadvisor but it has an issue when using it alongside Kubernetes [see open GH issue here](https://github.com/google/cadvisor/issues/3015). You could also use `kube_pod_container_status_last_terminated_reason{reason="OOMKilled"}` but then again it's not entirely accurate because it doesn't clear until a container is terminated for a different reason meaning it might be running and instead return such data. Last but not least you could use `node_vmstat_oom_kill` which as of today is working as expected, the downside of this one is that it works at node_level meaning it will not trigger only for a specific pod but for any pod having OOM issues (if you ask me this is good enough for alerting, regardless of it is a specific workload or not you want to get alerted when OOM its happening).

But if you need to use something that will give you the specific workload you could use a group_left between the `kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total` and the `kube_pod_container_status_last_terminated_reason` which should give you the restarts caused by OOM per workload... Something like the query below

```
sum by (namespace, pod) (kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total) * on(namespace, pod) group_left(reason) kube_pod_container_status_last_terminated_reason{reason="OOMKilled"}
```